# How to handle JSON data in SQL merge statement

Tags: c#, reactjs, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using a SQL `MERGE` statement for bulk insert/update/delete record, and also I am using "user defined table type" as parameter to pass bulk record from front end.

This scenario is working fine because user defined table type only accepts "DataTable" in C#. Now I am going to pass JSON data instead of DataTable to bulk record. Please advise how to handle JSON data in SQL `MERGE` statement.

Comment: JSON data can be "serialised" to a string. Unless you have some kind of special table schema in mind to store it, it's just a string like anything else.

Comment: That is assuming the merge key is not buried inside the JSON somewhere. If it is, you should decide whether you're going to extract the key on the C# side or in the database.